# pass variables through html files

Tags: javascript, html, var

I would like to know if there is any approach to pass `var`s through `.html` files.

For example in my `index.html` an `<a>` click sets this:

```
var value = 'some text here';
```

and links to `other.html`.
The first executed script in my `other.html` is:

```
console.log(value);
```

Is this somehow that HTML files can pass variables through?

Comment: Use the URL or a cookie. If URL then access `location.search` or `location.hash`

Comment: try opening your other.html as "other.html#yourVariableValue", then  in other.html var value = window.location.hash;

Answer (score 0):

You can send any data from one page to another by passing it as queryString like `host/other.html?value=something`

In first page append your data with the url using javascript or jquery and in second page retrieve it using javascript or jquery

Comment: Include the following function in your javascript 

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results === null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

Now you can take your passed values by using following line of code

var value= getParameterByName('value');